# Question aboute a quote from a TV show where I've noticed two different tenses in the same sentence

Tags: past-tense, future

there is a famous quote from Game of Thrones Episode 10 season 3 where a character says **"Any man who must say, "I am the king" is no true king. I'll make sure you understand that when I've won your war for you.**" I've noticed that there is two different tenses in the second part of the quote where we can see "I'll" which is supposed to refer to the future, and then he said "when I've won" which is supposed to refer to the past, so I'm a little bit confused, thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: The character, after he has helped win the war, will ensure X understands. At that point, the war will _have been_ won.

Comment: You do it as well - “I’ve noticed ... there is ...”. How is the example you quote different?

Comment: @Lawrence I think I get it now, but I'm not sure that what I said is similar to the quote.

Comment: The rule of thumb is that you don't use 'will' to refer to the future in conjunctions of time: when/until/as soon as/until/unless/after etc. Present or present perfect structures are common. I'll talk to you when I get there. She'll help you when she has finished. You might get more detailed answers on the English learners sites.

Comment: @SConroy It seems obvious now with the examples you gave, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second part of the second sentence uses the present perfect, which isn't exactly the past tense. The present perfect is used in the present to show a relationship to something done or completed in the past, almost always at a time close to the present.

For example, "I have done my homework" is something you would say in the present to acknowledge that, at some point shortly before the present, you completed your homework.

The first part of the second sentence is just the simple future ("I *will* make sure you understand...").

In this case, Tywin (the character) is saying that when he can say in the present that the war is won (by him), then he will (in the near future) be able to show the king that no true king needs to say "I am the king."

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think I get it now, it's like saying "I'll make sure you understand that (immediately) after winning the war for you", right ? that means the war isn't won yet ... ?

Comment: @MohammedBenbachir That's right. He's saying that he has to win the war first.

Comment: Alright, thanks again for your answer.